# Share button does not show the image from the shared link

Tags: facebook, shared

I do configure the Like and Share button on a website but the image that appear when a link is shared is not the same image fromthe link, it is some random image fromthe site

So another image is seen, but only when a user click on the link the right image is show.

How can i fix it ? any parameter ?

Comment: In my case it seems that the use of nordic characters or their urlencoded version in the page url stops Facebook from locationg the right picture. Even if og:image is specified and correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check what Facebook is detecting on your page using the Debug tool: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

If any of the Open Graph meta tags are missing on the links you're sharing, Facebook has to guess at the title/description/image/etc and it won't necessarily be the first/biggest/most prominent image or piece of text on the page